# Script to generate thumbs only if thumb doesn't exist

Tags: bash, files

I have a working script to generate thumbs to all pdf files in a folder( using Image Magic):

```
for f in *.pdf; do convert -thumbnail 250x200 "$f"[0]"_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg"; done
```

How can i adjust this to check if the "_thumb_wd_+"f"+.jpg exists? So i can generate the thumbs only if it does not exists!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` conditional construct to perform an action depending on some condition e.g. if something exists or not. In your case you need to put the action segment inside the `if-then` condition:

```bsh
  if ! [[ -f "_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg" ]]; then
    convert -thumbnail 250x200 "$f"[0]"_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg"
  fi
```

`[[` is a `bash` keyword, we are using it to check (`-f`) if the file `_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg` exists and is a regular file. The `!` negates the operation, as a result `convert` will only run if the file does not exist.

So, your final script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf; do
  if ! [[ -f "_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg" ]]; then
    convert -thumbnail 250x200 "$f"[0]"_thumb_wd_${f%.pdf}.jpg"
  fi
done
```

Comment: i was pretty close, but the "[[" got me here...can you tell me why the double "["?!

Comment: @LcrossPortugal: yes, you were.. also note that `[[` is an improved version of `test` (`[`) builtin of `bash`..you can check `help test` or the `[[` section of `man bash` to get more idea on the conditions....